# How to set visual studio navigation menu style?

Tags: mahapps.metro

Someone know how to set menunavigation style? In particular I want to create the same style of the navigation menu of visual studio. In the demo project there's one available but I don't understood how the style is set. This is the style:

[image]

UPDATE with my APP.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.TreeView.xaml" />
```

Before:
[image]
After mouse overlap:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS menu style is used by the `Styles.xaml` resource dictionary, just put it in the resources of the window, or if you want it in the hole app, in the `App.xaml`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Edit (ful app resources)**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Edit (only the menu style)**

using only the menu style is not possible for the hole app, you must add the resources where your menu is created.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Menu.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardMenuItem}" />
            <Style TargetType="Menu"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardMenu}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Main">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 2"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've already tried with your solution but, when I insert this code in my App.Xaml in the preview of the designer the mahapp style disappear, also when I start the debuggin, my UI became black for all control, and this is strange. What I doing wrong?

Comment: @Bender i have updated my answer, maybe you forgot to add the default MahApps keys.

Comment: Nope, see my update question, I've already this resources..Without your solution my app is colored blue, but when I add your resources my app UI became black and I want change only the menu style..

Comment: @Bender Updated my answer with now to get only the menu style.

Comment: Great! Now working! Just one question: my menu became black only when I put the mouse on it, but by default style is like grey, why happean this?

Comment: See my images example please